# alternate for google places autocomplete for react native projects?

Tags: react-native, google-api, google-places-autocomplete

are there any alternatives for google places autocomplete for react native, because to access google places autocomplete i need USD currency billing enabled for that, i don't have USD currency account

[image]

See it only has USD no other currency, i have billing enabled for google cloud platform and not for google maps platform
[image]

I tried to use api key which billing was enabled for google cloud platform using INR, i was getting below error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for alternative you can use mapbox or ArcGIS, but I think you don't have to have USD currency account, you can add any card to work with it, currently I am using google places api in Pakistan.

Comment: i specified more details about my problem, please check that i'm scratching my head for past 2 days